# How do I stop onsubmit form to trigger itself?

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm trying to console.log something whenever a submit button is pressed
But whenever the page is loaded ( or reloaded ) the data gets logged in console without even clicking on submit button

I've tried to remove onsubmit from form and put an onclick on my input but same result happened ( one quick note that I can get the 'Data' in console also with clicking, my problem is that I want it to log ONLY when the button is clicked or submitted )

This is my pug

```
html
    head
        title Welcome to Test
    body
        form(
            onsubmit=console.log('Data')
        )
            input(
                name='email'
                type = 'email'
            )
            input(
                type='submit'
            )
```

// I've also tried putting button instead of input

And I have another question to ask, since I'm super new to Pug I don't really know where to search for examples or stuff like that, If possible I'd appreciate a source for pug examples ( not the pug site itself ), thanks.

Comment: You have syntax error, you missing double quotes `form(onclick="console.log('Data')")`

Comment: @ZohirSalak I've changed it to form(onclick="console.log('Data')") and now neither when loading page nor clicking on submit logs it

Comment: Works for me [Here](https://codepen.io/Zohir/pen/dxpYRw?editors=1010)

Comment: @ZohirSalak You are correct, It worked, thanks!!